# Add fields/relationships to ImportMap or ImportFile entity in Dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to add some custom fields / relationships to ImportMap / ImportFile entity in Dynamic CRM 2011?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found that this entity is not customizable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/bb956596.aspx

Thanks